# How to override ResourceDictionary values

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, resourcedictionary, staticresource

I have a resource dictionary like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SpecialColor" Color="Yellow" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SpecialTemplate">
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource SpecialColor}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I add my resource dictionary to my page like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Style/Special.xaml" />
</Page.Resources>
```

I use the SpecialRectangle like this:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SpecialTemplate}" />
```

Question: How do I change the color?

**[update] I tried this, but it did not work for me:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Style/Special.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SpecialColor" Color="Red" />
</Page.Resources>
```

This also did not work:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Style/Special.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SpecialColor" Color="Red" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</Page.Resources>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options depending on conditions - mainly

1. Change color based on what?
2. Where is the `ContentPresenter` and if perf is more important or developer convenience/clear architecture is.

You can use template selector and use two templates instead of one, you can bind the `Fill` of the rectangle, you could use a `VisualStateManager`, you could use the [CCC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.containercontentchanging.aspx) event if you're in a `ListView` and want to have best possible performance with no bindings, you could also simply walk the visual tree and annoy a few people. :)

Comment: Well, but we need to override the `SpecialColor` `Style`. `SpecialColor` must be defined in the external `ResourceDictionary` or it cannot build. But it needs to be defined, customized, elsewhere.

Comment: Well, maybe you could merge that external dictionary into your page dictionary and then you'd replace it with another dictionary before triggering a reload of your UI to reevaluate the resources...

Comment: I definitely tried that first. Either I have the syntax incorrect or it doesn't work. I have updated the question with the syntax.

Comment: No, that won't work because this is a static resource so Special.xaml has already evaluated the resource with key "SpecialColor" to the one from Special.xaml. You need to provide two entire versions of special.xaml with different colors.

Comment: If you had two ResourceDictionaries called Colors.Red.xaml and Controls.XAML and you wanted to swap to Colors.Green.XAML, how can you handle this in the App.xaml? Seems like a reasonable thing.